# Change format of date string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to get always the same date string format for different user input string.

```
23.6.18
23.6.2018
23.06.18
23.06.2018
```

All these strings should result in DD.MM.YYYY

```
23.06.2018
```

Should I use momentJS for that? Right now I do not use that in my project.
My problem is, that the input strings are `string` elements, not a real date value.

Comment: possible duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: moment js is a good choice for a `date-picker`. You can also have a common method for DateToString parse to a JS `Date` object, just make sure you validate the user input before saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve your string values, so the year part in `23.06.18` will always be returned as `2018` and not `18`. Having proper data is always the best starting point in case you want your code to be as simple as possible.

Moving on, reverse your "date" value to ISO Date format, so Moment.js can understand. Like this:

`const validDate = date.split('.').reverse().join('-');`

Now, just pass `validDate` to `moment(validDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY');` and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this with moment:

```
moment('23.06.18', 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('DD.MM.YYYY')
```

You may check the doc here:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/